In Laravel-Mix V6 How Can I Display SASS @Warn Messages in the Console?
I am using Laravel-Mix version 6 in a project and I would like to be able to display SCSS @warn output in the console for debugging and troubleshooting.  By default it, these messages are suppressed.
// example SCSS file
@warn "theme colors";
@warn $theme-colors;

I suspect the solution lives somewhere in the webpack.mix.js config file, but I'm unsure which setting to tweak.  I was able to get the messages to show by adding the following Webpack config setting:
mix.webpackConfig({
    stats: {
        all: true
    }
});

The problem is that this shows everything and it can be challenging to isolate just the @warn messages from the massive wall of text.  Is there a way to keep the console output lean, but include any @warn messages?
For reference, I am using:

laravel-mix@6.0.49
sass@1.77.2
webpack@5.91.0

Any assistance would be most appreciated!
